# No binary after python3-pygments

Tags: apt, python, binary

I need pygmentize for my Latex document. Since minted seems to work only with the python3 version, I want to install python3-pygments. (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS)

Now that seems to work at first, but then it can't be called:

```
me@mypc:~$ sudo apt install python3-pygments
[...]
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  python3-pygments
[...]
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../python3-pygments_2.1+dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Entpacken von python3-pygments (2.1+dfsg-1) ...
python3-pygments (2.1+dfsg-1) wird eingerichtet ...
me@mypc:~$ pygmentize -V
Die Anwendung »pygmentize« ist momentan nicht installiert. Sie können sie durch folgende Eingabe installieren:
sudo apt install python-pygments
```

Sorry for the german language, but it basically says that pygmentize is currently not installed.
How do I get it up and running?

Comment: Its saying "The application »pygmentize« is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: " ..I can install the python2 version, but that doesn't work with minted/latex.

Comment: Do you have the package installed? `apt list python3-pygments --installed`? What binary does the command currently invoke: `which pygmentize`?

Comment: @StephenKitt: Is that the answer?  Is the stuff in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/`installed but the executable missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04, the `pygmentize` binary is provided by the `python-pygments` package, using the Python 2 module. In my experiments, `minted` works fine with the Python 2 version of `pygments` — it invokes the `pygmentize` binary, and whether that’s implemented using Python 2 or Python 3 doesn’t make any difference as far as `minted` is concerned.

To reproduce, run

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra python-pygments
```

and process a `minted`-using document with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape ...
```

Starting with version 2.3.1+dfsg-1 of the `python3-pygments` package, the `pygmentize` binary is the Python 3 version; you’ll find that in Debian 10 or later and Ubuntu 20.04 or later.